For real matrix $M$ and complex vector $v$, is $M(\operatorname{Re}(v))=\operatorname{Re}(M(v))$?
Let $M \in \mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ be real-valued $n\times n$ matrix, and $v =\operatorname{Re}(v)+ i\operatorname{Im}(v) \in \mathbb C^n$ a complex vector. Does it then hold:
\begin{align}
M(\operatorname{Re}(v))&=\operatorname{Re}(M(v)), \\ M(\operatorname{Im}(v))&=\operatorname{Im}(M(v))?
\end{align}

It suffices to write it out. For every $1\leq i\leq n$, we have:
$$(Mv)_i=\sum_{j=1}^n M_{ij}v_j.$$
Taking real parts:
$$\mathrm{Re}(Mv)_i=\mathrm{Re}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n M_{ij}v_j\right)=\sum_{j=1}^n\mathrm{Re}(M_{ij}v_j)=\sum_{j=1}^n M_{ij}\mathrm{Re}(v_j).$$
The second equality uses that $\mathrm{Re}$ is additive, and the third one that $M_{ij}$ is real.
The above shows that $\mathrm{Re}(Mv)=M\mathrm{Re}(v)$, and the same works when you take the imaginary part.

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Just write $v=x+iy$ with $x,y$ real vectors.
$Mv=M(x+iy)=Mx+M(iy)=\underbrace{Mx}_{\in\mathbb R}+i\,\underbrace{My}_{\in\mathbb R}\quad$ by linearity.
But then $\Re(Mv)=Mx=M\Re(v)$ and same for imaginary part.
